# Where are the properties stored in prototypes are saved?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, prototype

if an object instance is created so the property defined with its prototype will not be attached to this instance until we define a value for the prototype property.

My question is where are the prototype properties of any instance are stored? And if those properties are stored in the same instance then what would be the advantage of using the prototype as it consumes the same memory space?

Comment: The prototype properties are stored in the prototype and no there is just *one* prototype for all instances

Comment: If it was stored separately for all instances then a change in prototype would require changes in all child instances. Therefore, instance will refer to the properties stored in a prototype itself.

Comment: @JonasW. yes, there will be only one prototype for all instances but where is the value for that prototype is stored? and if it is stored in the same instance then it will consume same memory as it would take without use prototype. So what is the advantages of using the prototype?

Comment: @gurvinder372, I just want to know whether this will occupy same space in the memory as it would take without use of prototype?

Comment: I think you dont get the concept of *references*

Comment: @JonasW. I would appreciate if you explain me. Maybe you can provide me some links or anything that can clear my doubt.

Comment: [See the *call by sharing* section](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy)

Answer (score 1):

> My question is where are the prototype properties of any instance are
>   stored? And if those properties are stored in the same instance then
>   what would be the advantage of using the prototype as it consumes the
>   same memory space?

**Tl, Dr**

*Prototype properties* of the *parent Object* are **inherited**, hence they are not stored in the *individual instance* of the same.

These *individual instance* keep a reference to the *prototype's properties* so that if the *prototype's property* changes, it is then reflected in each of the *instance object*.

**Example**

Lets take an example of an object.

```
var obj = function(){};
```

Add a property `a1` into `obj`

```
obj.prototype.a1 = 1;
```

Create a child instance `childObj1` of `obj` and check if the prototype properties are inherited.

```
var childObj1 = new obj();
console.log( childObj1 ); //show a1
```

Create another property `a2` of `obj` and check if the prototype properties are inherited.

```
obj.prototype.a2 = 2;
console.log( childObj1 ); //show a1 and a2
```

Create another child instance `childObj2` of `obj` and check if the prototype properties are inherited.

```
var childObj2 = new obj();
console.log( childObj2 ); //show a1 and a2

obj.prototype.a3 = 3;
console.log( childObj1 ); //show a1, a2 and a3
console.log( childObj2 ); //show a1, a2 and a3
```

```js
var obj = function(){};

obj.prototype.a1 = 1;

var childObj1 = new obj();
console.log( childObj1 ); //show a1

obj.prototype.a2 = 2;
console.log( childObj1 ); //show a1 and a2

var childObj2 = new obj();
console.log( childObj2 ); //show a1 and a2

obj.prototype.a3 = 3;
console.log( childObj1 ); //show a1, a2 and a3
console.log( childObj2 ); //show a1, a2 and a3
```

Comment: Well explained..! I want to ask what happens if we do this :-

childObj1.a1 = 234;

Will this a1 be stored to the instance memory or anywhere else?

Comment: Only a1 value will be updated, since you are updating the instance's property rather than instance's prototype's property that it has inherited